“Choose Your Own Adventure” with time travel and some very bizarre scenes in it from the 1980s or early 1990s
I’m looking for a “Choose Your Own Adventure” book (or more likely a  “Choose Your Own Adventure” knock-off) which involved time travel and had a couple of very specific sections that really stood out to me.  This would have been 1980s-era or possibly early 1990s.  Here’s what I remember about it:

I remember it feeling pretty derivative of The Cave of Time, so much so that I think it’s unlikely to be a “Choose Your Own Adventure”-branded book.
In general, the scenarios and plot elements were really wacky, even by  “Choose Your Own Adventure” standards. Real fever-dream stuff.
There was a scene where you end up in the middle of a battle in what is probably the Middle Ages or Dark Ages. There are a bunch of warriors with their faces painted blue, Braveheart-style.
There was an especially bizarre section where you found yourself on a ledge or platform in a room with a bottomless pit.  Suspended on wires from the ceiling were two large stuffed animals; one was a bumblebee and one was something else.  Your only hope of escape was to jump and grab one of the animals (and, I guess, swing to the other side of the room? I dunno).  If you chose the bee, it gave you an electric shock and you fell into the pit.  I swear I am not making this up.
It's possible the blue-faced warriors and the electric bee are from different books and I'm just conflating them, but I feel like they were in the same book.

The book was so gratuitously weird that I thought I would have no trouble tracking it down, but so far I’ve had no luck.

https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/1c3y2k1/choose_your_own_adventure_with_time_travel_and/ - It's generally a good idea to mention where else you've posted the question.

Also https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1c2k8mj/tomtbook_choose_your_own_adventure_with_time/

A bunch of science fiction themed CYOA style books at https://gamebooks.org/Category/33 , a lot to go through but you could just see if any of the titles ring a bell

Have you ruled out. The Time Raider: Twistaplot Book by R.L. Stine who later wrote Goosebumps.
It involves time travel and is very weird. There is a blue faced man, an emperor in the future. The Emperor's soldiers also have blue faces. In one ending you are transformed into a chicken to lay eggs for the Emperor.You can travel back in time and save the lives of your uncle and father as boys. You can save a young Daniel Boone from a bear. You can be turned into a bear and attack your time travelling human self. You can have your brain replaced by a robotic one.
I have now read every page. The closest things to your bumblebee I found were a not very similar bat and dodo.


Yes, I ruled that one out.  I wish I could remember anything about the cover, or even how it started. Something like that would probably help a lot.

Wow, that was above and beyond, thanks for doing that. It's definitely not the right book, but I appreciate it!

You are welcome.
